# How to upload multiple image upload without submit button using ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to upload multiple image upload without submit button   using ajax jquery?Can someone help my finding out whats wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">     </script>
```

Here is the code

```html
  <body> 
    <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenval" id="hiddenval" value="">
    <button id="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
    var outputdata = [];

    $.ajax({
      url: "upload1.php",
      type: "POST",
       data: new Form(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(files, data, xhr) {
        outputdata.push(files);
        $('#hiddenval').val(outputdata)
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Bootstrap CSS (3.3.6) and JS (3.3.7) versions?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i'm getting a warning"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in path"

Comment: That's because you're providing a reference to a button (the `#upload` element) to the `FormData` constructor. It needs to be a `form` element instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i have changed the formdata ,still its not upload the image.

Comment: We can't really help without seeing what you changed it to. Please edit your question to show the updated code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, code updated....idon't know the right format..i'm new to jquery..

Comment: You still need to use a `FormData` object - you need to provide a reference to a `<form>` element as the argument to the constructor. If you don't have one you'll need to `append()` the file data manually. Here's a clearer example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 2):

add id to this input for easier get value.

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple id="files"/>
```

Includes values from this input to data:

```
$(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
    var outputdata = [];
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('files');
    var files = fileSelect.files;
    var formData = new FormData();
    // Loop through each of the selected files.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        // Check the file type.
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        // Add the file to the request.
        formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
    }

    $.ajax({  
        url: "upload1.php",  
        type: "POST",  
        data: formData,  
        contentType: false,  
        processData:false,  
        success: function(files,data,xhr)  
        {           
           outputdata.push(files);
           $('#hiddenval').val(outputdata);
        }  
    }); 
});
```

Refer: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Comment: **Note:** I'm not sure if the 3rd parameter is required when using `.append`, I missed it out and everything worked as intended. Either way, excellent answer.